# tinyxml cannot parse const char* correctly

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I use **tinyxml2** to deal with a string that contains xml. I use the function `Parse` but it just read a part of the string and return **`XML_SUCCESS`**

```cpp
#include "XML/include/tinyxml2.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string xml("<application> <name>something</name> </application>");

    tinyxml2::XMLDocument xmlDoc;
    if (tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS == xmlDoc.Parse(xml.c_str(), xml.size()))
    {
        tinyxml2::XMLElement* pNode = xmlDoc.FirstChildElement("name");
        std::cout << pNode->GetText() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will throw a exception that tell me the `pNode` is a `nullptr` and I checked the `_charBuffer` of the xmlDoc.

It just contain

```
<application
```

Comment: can you try one more time but without spaces in the xml string

Comment: I have tried the "<application><name>something</name></application>" version and the result is the same.

Comment: Does xmlDoc have a `FirstChildElement("application")`? I'm not sure but I think tinyxml has a 'root' element above all the elements in the XML document.

Comment: @mangusta whitespace between elements is allowed by the XML spec and parses will ignore it unless told to preserve it

Comment: @RemyLebeau not always. java's dom parser treats spaces as separate elements. unrelated to this question though

Comment: @mangusta that behavior can be controlled with [`XMLParser.setPreserveWhitespace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b12024/oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParser.html#setPreserveWhitespace(boolean))

Comment: @RemyLebeau I mean that some parsers default to reading whitespaces as elements while others default to ignoring them. java's dom parser allows controlling, probably there exists a parser out there which does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the question is that xmlDoc do not contain "name".
It's the "application" contains the "name"

```cpp
tinyxml2::XMLElement* pRoot = xmlDoc.RootElement();
tinyxml2::XMLElement* pNode = pRoot->FirstChildElement("name");
```